# Класс матрица

Tags: матрицы, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать класс матрица и переопределить оператор умножения.

1. Разработать класс «матрица», данные которого содержат квадратную вещественную матрицу произвольного размера, а методы необходимы для изменения данных и решения задачи из пункта 2. В функции main() создайте объект разработанного класса и выведите на консоль куб исходной матрицы.
2. Входной файл содержит квадратную вещественную матрицу. Программа должна читать описание матрицы из входного файла и выводить в выходной файл квадрат, куб исходной матрицы, её определитель, а также обратную матрицу, если последняя существует. Формат входного файла: в первой строке задаётся число строк и столбцов в матрице, в последующих – элементы, разделённые произвольным количеством пробелов. Имена входного и выходного файлов передаются через аргументы командной строки. Если имя выходного файла не задано, вывод осуществляется на экран. Если не задано имя входного файла, программа должна печатать справку об использовании и завершать свою работу. Все ошибочные ситуации должны корректно обрабатываться программой!

Comment: @Тёма, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уважаемый [[@tabby_cat](/users/11292/tabby_cat)](/users/11292/tabby_cat), конечно, прав, и писать за Вас код здесь никто не станет. Но гуманитарную помощь, в смысле общего напрвления мыслей, оказать можно. В "основе" класса может находиться либо vector<vector<double> >, либо указатель `**double`. В обоих случаях придется перегрузить оператор []. Пишете конструкторы, коструктор копии, оператор = и, в случаае `**double` - деструктор. Код оператора * слишком простой, посмотрите в учебниках. Определитель вычисляют для квадратной матрицы методом исключения Гаусса, на прямом ходе, как аккумулированое произведение диагональных членов (делителей) перед каждой итерацией. Полезно будет в методе Гаусса произвести поиск главной строки. В функции матрицу передавайте по ссылке.

Comment: +1, но по поводу индексов: http://hashcode.ru/questions/178553/

Comment: Уважаемый @VladD, хочется сохранить синтаксис массивов С++, а не возвращаться к давно забытому Бэйсику.

Comment: @BuilderC: ну, официальный C++ FAQ рекомендует синтаксис с круглыми скобочками (*развожу руками*).

Comment: Ну, дайте дожить с квадратными!

Comment: Marshall Cline неумолим :-\

Comment: Вас уже обвиняли в жестокости, а Вы опять... :-)